# Filtering substring from a geojson string column in Mapbox GL JS

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I am trying to filter my Mapbox map based on a substring filter.

I have a column called COUNTY which has strings like `Kern,Ventura,Los Angeles`.

My current code is as follows -

```
 map.addLayer({
    id: "poly",
    type: "fill",
    source: "poly_source",
    layout: {},
    paint: {
      "fill-color": "red",
      "fill-opacity": 0.8,
    },
    filter: ["all",
    ["==", "YEAR_", "1923"],
    ["in","COUNTY","Los Angeles"],
    ]
  });
```

As I understand from [Mapbox Docs](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#in), it should be actually getting the rows with strings like `Kern,Ventura,Los Angeles`. But in my map, I'm only getting the rows which has just `Los Angeles`.

How can I go about fixing this?

Comment: Maybe all rows with `YEAR_ = "1923"` are just the rows with `COUNTY = "Los Angeles"`.

Comment: I did check the data, there are rows for 1923 where there are multiple counties.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
filter: ["all", ["==", "YEAR_", 1923], ["in", "COUNTY", "Los Angeles"]]
```

or

```
filter: ["all", ["==", ["get", "YEAR_"], 1923], ["in", ["get", "COUNTY"], "Los Angeles"]]
```

Comment: In my original code, I have tried the first method you mentioned. I just tried the second method and it doesn't work. I still get the same results. For 1923 I only get the polygons where the COUNTY is just "Los Angeles" and I don't get the polygons with where COUNTY is "Kern, Ventura, Los Angeles".